# Is there a justification for past simple

Tags: past-tense

McGuinn  had a better idea: recording an electric version version of Pete Seeger's ,"turn!turn!turn!" immortal folk prayer. "Turn!turn!turn!", which Seeger **adapted** from the Book of Ecclesiastes. Back in his New York session days, Mc Guinn had arranged the song in a chamber-folk for Judy Collins.

I am wondering why it is not **had adapted** because when Mc Guinn wanted to record this song,it had already been fully adapted  by Pete Seeger, it would have been different if it had been written "Turn, turn, turn adapted by, adapted would be a past participle.

So why past simple I don't understand, may be the  reason  is that the meaning is clear enough

the Byrds boxset included a book where I found this

Comment: He did the adapting at a point in time and the author is not trying to make the point that the adapting came earlier. He or she could have but he or she didn't. Not every thing in the past has to be preceded by a verb in the PP. Only if that is your point.

Comment: OK But is it little ambiguous in the meaning we could think that the adaptation was done just before Mc Guinn  recorded  it

Comment: I think he wants to make the point that Pete Seeger adapted the song from the Book of Ecclesiastes, he wants to state that fact. Later on it says Mc Guinn had arranged, maybe he wants to avoid using too many past perfects in one paragraph.

Comment: There is no ambiguity at all. There **is something** wrong in your post re form. It should be something like: McGuinn had a better idea: recording an electric version of Pete Seeger's immortal folk prayer, "Turn!turn!turn!", which Seeger adapted from the Book of Ecclesiastes.

Comment: user5577: Ordinarily, we wouldn't ***care*** how much time there was between the act of adapting and the act of recording. And it's obvious without being stated that one precedes the other. Introducing a Perfect form just misleadingly implies that there's something "meaningful" about the sequence, that needs to be emphasised. Note that *Mc Guinn **had** arranged the song* is a completely meaningless choice - it would make no difference whatsoever if ***had*** wasn't there (but there's nothing *wrong*, either way).

Comment: why meaningless